# Redirecting home to page in subdirectory, mask url

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm using wordpress.

I'd like my site's domain root to display contents of another page while still showing my domain root as the url.

EXAMPLE:  "http://www.mysite.com" displays contents of "http://www.mysite.com/blogs/home"
but users still see "http://www.mysite.com" in the address bar.

I've managed to get the redirect working, but it's not masking the URL.  It essentially is redirecting.

Here's what I have now in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\/?$ \/blogs\/home\/ [R,NC]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question very well... you want `http://www.mysite.com` to disappear from the URL?

Comment: No, I only want them to see ONLY "mysite.com" and not the extra "/blogs/home/"

Answer (score 1):

The R option forces an external redirect. Try just `[NC]` instead

Comment: Thanks, but tried that too.  Tried all combinations of L, R, NC... since I don't really know what I'm doing, but I know they do something.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ /blogs/home [NC,P]
```

PS: Make sure you have mod_proxy enabled in your Apache config.

Comment: Thank you but this is giving me a 404.  The URL is properly displaying just the domain, though.

Comment: Oh sorry I had a typo. Instead of `blogs/home` I had `blog/home`. Try now the edited answer.

Comment: Actually, no.  In my tired haste, it was displaying the contents of /blogs/ not /blogs/home/.  Sorry.  I think Wordpress is probably doing something.  The htaccess it provides is this:
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blogs/index.php [L]

Comment: Ok pls check the edited answer now. You will need to make sure that mod_proxy is enabled on your Apache server. See this setting working here: http://freedomteam.in/

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  The change alone gave me a 404, so perhaps I don't have mod_proxy enabled... but I use Dreamhost and am not sure how to make that change. I'm going to write support and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

what about this way.

1. put the index.php and .htaccess file in the root of your domain.
2. edit index.php to grab the "wp-blog-header.php" file from what ever location you put it. For example, if your wordpress file is located in blogs/home/ sub directory, you change the index.php file located in the root directory as   require('./blogs/home/wp-blog-header.php').
3. forget about the redirect issue.

I think this is the easiest way. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I can try this tomorrow.  But to clarify things more, my wordpress install is located in /blogs/ directory.  /blogs/home/ is actually a page (AKA /blogs/?p=1484)

Comment: So what this did was show the page I wanted, but didn't end up fooling the URL to only display the root domain.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple solutions to this problem. In fact wordpress has an option to accomplish this task.

Go to **Dashboard->Settings->Reading->Front page displays**

Select a static page as front page.

Comment: You missed the most important aspect which is the url.  The big picture is, I have a wordpress install on the /blogs/ subdirectory and I truly want 99% of the pages to be within the /blogs/ directory... except the one designated page, which I want to be in the root.

Comment: I really don't get the point of installing wordpress on **/blog/** when you want it to appear on **root** of your domain. Please explain a little more and I might be able to suggest an idea.

Comment: I had a static html website with a blog section, installed on blog.  I've made the decision to power the entire website with wordpress. So I'm trying to figure out a way to do that without changing the URLs to all the old blog posts... not out of concern for the user, but because when the URL changes, all the social stats (FB Likes, Shares) return to 0.  Since posting this I've decided to essentially use your method, but I've not been able to keep the blogs the same URL because, well it's complicated, but I'm getting there...

Comment: Ok I think I get what you are trying to do. You want all wordpress posts URLs to be followed by **root/blog/** but you want your homepage on root? Am I right?

Comment: I think you got it, yes.  The problems I'm running into all have to do with the fact that the WP core files still reside in the /blogs/ directory so that's screwing up the redirects, since it's already trying to redirect away from /blogs/.  So I will either have to change the name of the directory WP is in, or physically move the whole thing into the root.

Comment: If I were you I would go with second idea. Move whole WP installation into root. And prefix permalink structure for posts with **/blog/** so your SEO and social stats don't get hurt.